# Removing the borders of a window in ExtJs 4.2

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

```
var myWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    header: false,
    style: 'background-color: transparent; border: false',
    bodyStyle: 'background-color: transparent; background-image: url(graphics/ss_message.png); background-size: 100% 100%;',
    id: 'ss_banner',
    width: 250,
    height: component.getBox().height,
    border: false,
    bodyBorder: false,
    frame: false,
    cls: 'noPanelBorder',
});
```

I'm using the window xtype because I can't seem to make a container/panel appear, even if I add `renderTo: Ext.getBody()`, it doesn't work.

The window appears as such:

[image]

I've also tried to use css I'm rather unsure on which properties to use.

Comment: Could you provide a working fiddle showing your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Removing window border**

If you really want to remove borders of a window, you can use following configuration:

```
var myWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {

    // ...

    // What shows the 'border' is actually just the background of the window
    // shown via padding (+ 1px of actual border)
    style: 'padding: 0; border-width: 0;',
    // Show automatically
    autoShow: true,
    // Disable resizing, if you want
    resizable: false,
});
```

Here is a working fiddle of [removing window borders](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1q3p)

**Showing a panel**

However, if you don't want to use any of the window functionality and could do with a container or a panel, you should use them. All you should need is the `renderTo` configuration you mentioned, to render the panel to the body or to any other element. I don't know why this configuration does not work for you, it works perfectly in the fiddle below.

You can try adding a unique class to the panel via `cls` configuration property and search for it in the rendered HTML code. It is possible it is rendered correctly and just not visible for some reason.

Here is a working fiddle of [rendering panel to element](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1q3q)

**EDIT:**
If you need to display only image, there is an image component in ExtJS, `Ext.Img`. You can work with this component the same way I described for the panel.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var myWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    // What shows the 'border' is actually just the background of the window
    // shown via padding (+ 1px of actual border)
    style: 'padding: 0; border-width: 0;',
});
```